# 2012 Chevy Traverse Broken Latch on the dashboard storage compartment

Tags: dashboard

The latch on my 2012 Chevy Traverse broke and I need a new one, I'm being told, they don't have just the latch, that I have to replace the entire dashboard that includes this storage bin which is about $200 not including installation, which I refuse to do. Any ideas on how to get this storage bin to close as it's in the way of my view while driving, I've done two sided tape, glue, etc. and it won't stay down for long before it pops back open. Help, any ideas??[image: Dashboard Storage Bin]

Comment: Show the detail of the latch part that is broken then consider making a new part for that. Or visit a scrap yard.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! As a flippant answer, I'd suggest some Duct Tape, however, I'm sure the aesthetics may run afoul for you ;-) Really, either buying a new latch (as you've suggested you don't want to do) or going to a scrap yard as Mike suggested, or possibly finding someone who is parting out a vehicle like yours ... Looking on CriagsList or the like may be a place where you could find something like that.

Comment: Take it apart and remove the springs that make it pop up.

Comment: The pic in this post is the storage compartment I'm talking about, this latch that is circled broke off and is missing. When it broke, it flew off and I can't find it anywhere. So strange. I will post a pic of mine as it sits in my vehicle shortly.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike. Paulster2, I would love to buy just the latch but Chevy tells me they don't sell that little part, I'd have to buy the entire dashboard that includes this compartment and that latch. I'm not willing to do that. I'm frustrated enough, I may do the duck tape. lol.

Comment: Good idea Moab, I may try to do that tonight. Thanks so much!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAN6Zbf9HEw   even she had the same issue with that latch....

Comment: Very good idea @Moab

Comment: $200, you could purchase a 3d printer for that price. Get a roll of ABS, and print your own replacement component. Or just go to a local junkyard.

Comment: @KarenCushman I suggested a scrapyard, not a chevy dealer - unless you consider them the same.